# Why does "docker start" disallow parameters as "-a stdin -a stdout"?

Tags: docker, concept

The [Docker Doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) says:

`docker run` = `docker create` + `docker start`

Consider the following command:

`docker run -a stdin -a stdout image_id bash`

I cannot think out the commands using `docker create` + `docker start` equivalent to `docker run -a stdin -a stdout image_id bash`.

`docker create -a stdin -a stdout image_id bash` is ok.

If I use `docker start -a container_id`, then all of stdin, stdout, and stderr will be attached. But I just want stdin and stdout to be attached.

If I use `docker start container_id`, then nothing will be attached.

Both cases are not what `docker run -a stdin -a stdout image_id bash` exactly did.

I just wonder, is it really true that `docker run` = `docker create` + `docker start` ?

Comment: Yes. docker run = docker create + docker start.

Comment: Create: adds a writeable container on top of your image and sets it up for running whatever command you specified in your CMD. The container ID is reported back but it’s not started.

Start: will start any stopped containers. This includes freshly created containers.

Run: is a combination of create and start. It creates the container and starts it.

Comment: How do you use create and start to attach stdout but not sterr?@MuhammadKamran